# Using method of an extended class in a class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I'm trying to use a method of an extended class in the extended one (this is probably not really clear but look at the example below and you will understand).

My module is made in typescript :

```
export default class Test1 {
  private storedCond: string;

  public cond = (cond: string) => {
    this.storedCond = cond;
    return this.storedCond.length;
  };
  public getStoredCond = () => this.storedCond;
}
```

And then i want to use is some how like so in a js file :

```
import Test1 from './modules/Test1';

class Test2 extends Test1 {
  // this line is not working, how can i make it work ?
  this.cond('a futur dynamic string');

  final = () => `${this.getStoredCond()} is ${this.getStoredCond().length} length`;
}

const test = new Test2();

console.log(test.final());
```

My `Test1` module is a little bit like a store, i could do something like this : `sotredCond = this.cond('a futur dynamic string');` in my `Test2` class but this is not what i want to do. I want to give a string (`cond`) in my `Test2` class and store it in my `Test1` module.

Comment: If you wanting this to automatically run the `this.cond` you will want to put that in the constructor..

Comment: you can't rich that result with extend class, you should create an instance of Test1 on your Test2 class and call function with binding to Test1 class. and if you want to use that cond for other modules you should create you Test1 class as singleton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @Nathan Bruet's answer works but this is not what i really want to do.

But the comment of @Keith is right.

The the final code of my Test2 class is :

```
class Test2 extends Test1 {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.cond('a futur dynamic string');
  }

  final = () =>
    `${this.getStoredCond()} is ${this.getStoredCond().length} length`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **constructor** in your class `Test2`

```
import Test1 from './modules/Test1';

class Test2 extends Test1 {

  constructor(cond: string) {
    this.cond(cond);
  }

  public final = () => `${this.getStoredCond()} is ${this.getStoredCond().length} length`;
}

const test = new Test2('a futur dynamic string');

console.log(test.final());
```

Each time you call `new Test2(arg)` the constructor will be executed.

See documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

Comment: this is wrong answer he just want to give a string (cond) in Test2 class and store it in Test1 module.